# How to vote for questions with ambiguities between title and explanation?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/869/was-bedeutet-in-der-schweiz-sind-sie-bedient) about a phrase I heard in some real situation. Which I described with only a few words.

There is some ambiguity insofar as the phrase by itself has some additional possible answers, outside the context I had in mind.

In the comments I tried to focus on this context. At this point a third person downvoted the answer for not reading the question.

It is a bit ridiculous. The oritinal poster (me) and the answerer are native German speakers who expressed themselves in English and didn't grook the ambiguities.

I think using downvoting here is complete overshoot.

> Finally I decided to vote up answers
>   which were correct and valuable with
>   respect to the question title. The
>   value we produce is that people
>   asking in search engines will be
>   directed to the most valuable
>   information.
>
> Giving an answer for the special
>   situation of my question is a reason
>   to accept the answer.

One of the problems with this site is that people with no *vertragssicherem* (please give a translation as comment) English are encouraged to write in English. And there is a good chance that two of them have more misunderstandings as when just using German.

Übrigens weiß ich gar nicht, warum ich hier auf meta Englisch schreibe, Ihr wollt doch schließlich Deutsch lernen oder könnt es sowieso. Also springt schon ins kalte Wasser.

Und schließlich finde ich, diese Seite sollte für alle Sprecher anderer Fremdsprachen wertvoll sein, die deutsche Sprache lernen wollen, und nicht nur für die englischsprachigen.

Die Bereiche Übersetzung aus dem Englischen und ins Englische sind naturgemäß am besten zweisprachig zu handhaben.

Comment: Schreib auf jeden Fall in Deutsch wenn du das möchtest. Ich empfand diese besondere Frage als etwas seltsam. Da der Titel in Deutsch ist, der erste Text auf Englisch und dann am die Erklärung doch wieder auf Englisch. Am besten wäre es in meinen Augen gewesen das einfach ganz auf deutsch zu machen. Ich hab meine Downvotes gecastet (haut mich für denglisch ^^) weil ich dich scheinbar verstanden habe, und dann natürlich entsprechend der Diskussion auch wieder zurückgezogen. Ich halte Downvoten für das richtige Mittel, dafür bleibe ich allerdings auch aufmerksam auf die Veränderung der Antworten.

Comment: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/443/questions-and-their-translations-fragen-und-ihre-bersetzungen

Answer (score 3):

Bernd, wenn Du im Englischen unsicher bist, schreib auf Deutsch - das ist kein Problem, und bei echtem Bedarf wird sich jemand finden, der die Frage übersetzt.

Ich finde es akzeptabel, Fragen oder Antworten *downzuvoten*, die unverständlich erscheinen. Man sollte dann aber einen Kommentar hinterlassen und ein Auge auf etwaige Edits haben, sodass man den Downvote wieder zurücknehmen kann.

Comment: Downvotes, um den Autor falscher Antworten zum Überarbeiten zu bewegen, sind ja OK. Das Problem hier ist eher, das die Ausgangssituation noch nicht durch Rückfragen geklärt war. Für mein Gefühl kam der Downvote zu früh.

Comment: Er wurde ja wieder zurückgenommen. Nicht persönlich nehmen. Aber nicht nur Antworten, auch Fragen sollten gewisse Qualitätskriterien erfüllen; auf dba.SE oder SO erlebst Du doch sicher häufiger Fragen, die letztlich nur auf "schreibt mir meine Hausaufgabe" hinauslaufen oder unverständlich sind - sowas wird dann eben downgevotet.

Comment: Auf dba.SE haben wir wenig Probleme mit _Homework_ Fragen, obwohl dort zurückhaltend moderiert wird. Hauptsächlich geht es um Duplikate und ein paar Migrationen zu anderen Seiten. Bei SO stimme ich dir zu.

Answer (score 0):

> It is a bit ridiculous. The oritinal poster (me) and the answerer are native German speakers who expressed themselves in English and didn't grook the ambiguities.

It is indeed ridiculous. You could have asked your question in German. Then there would have been no problem …